# Laravel Collections counting result

Tags: php, laravel, collections

On a User model (table with 4 records), when I do:

```
$coll = User::all();
echo $coll->count();
```

I get the amount of records found (4).

But when I do:

```
$coll = User::find(2);
echo $coll->count();
```

I do not get 1 (As I expect) but the amount of attributes in the resulting collection (23 in this case).

How can I check if more then one records are found?

---

**UPDATE:**

OK, thanks to you all I now see the difference in result between collection and model.

But my real problem is that I have to detect if I am having a model or a collection as a result. Depending on this result I perform some changes on the contents of the fields in the items (with map()) or model. How can I detect if the result is a model or a collection?

```
if(count($coll) > 1)
```

Works, but is this the right approach?

Comment: I don't believe `::find()` returns a collection, actually.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Actually it can, if you pass it an array of id's. But in this case if the entry with an `id = 2` is found it will return an Eloquent Model.

Comment: @Bogdan, Good point. I guess I should have said more specifically `::find(2)` does not return a collection.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's what's going on with the code you have there:

**1.** When calling `User::all()` you'll get a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` on which you can call [`count`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_count) which counts the elements in the collection like so:

```
public function count()
{
    return count($this->items);
}
```

This will return the number of items in the collection as you correctly expected.

**2.** When calling `User::find(2)` however, the Eloquent Query Builder will not return a `Collection`, because it will check to see how many results there are, and since you passed **one ID** you'll get at most **one result**, so it will return an Eloquent Model instead. The Model does not have a `count()` method, so when you try to call `$coll->count();` it will go to the magic [`__call`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method___call) method that the class has implemented which looks like this:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, array('increment', 'decrement')))
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $parameters);
    }

    $query = $this->newQuery();

    return call_user_func_array(array($query, $method), $parameters);
}
```

As you can see the method tries to see if it should call a couple of hardcoded methods (`increment` and `decrement`), which of course don't match in this case because `$method = 'count'`, so it continues to create a new Query on which it will call the `count` method.

The bottom line is that both the first and second code samples end up doing the same thing: **counting all the entries in the `users` table**.

And since, as I pointed our above, one ID cannot match more than one row (since IDs are unique), the **answer to your question** is that there's no need or way to count the results of `find(2)`, since it can only be 0 (if `null` is returned) or 1 (if a `Model` is returned).

---

**UPDATE**

First of all, for future reference you can use the PHP [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) to determine the class name of an object or [`get_parent_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php) to determine the class it is extending. In your case the second function `get_parent_class` might be useful for determining the model class since the `User` class extends a Laravel abstract Model class.

So if you have a model `get_class($coll)` will report `User`, but `get_parent_class($coll)` will report `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

Now to check if the result is a Collection or a Model you can use [`instanceof`](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php):

> `instanceof` is used to determine whether a PHP variable is an instantiated object of a certain class

Your checks should look something like this:

```
// Check if it's a Collection
if ($coll instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection)

// Check if it's a Model
if ($coll instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model)
```

You might also want to check if the result is `null`, since `find` will return `null` if no entry is found with the given ID:

```
if (is_null($coll))
```

Comment: Of course! I did not make the difference between a collection and a model. Thanks for clearing this for me! Please see the updated question for the real solution I am looking for.

Comment: @Klaaz I've updated the answer with the solution to your updated question.

Comment: Great! This makes things very clear, thank you for explaining :-)

Comment: The `Collection` has its own method `$collection->count()`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are expecting the [find()-method](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_find) to behave differently. From the [docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_find)

```
Find a model by its primary key.
```

Comment: Laravel broke lots of documentation links during a redesign at some point, so these old API links are dead.

Answer (score 0):

If you problem is by checking if its from collection. Why don't you check it if its from Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection.

```
if (get_class($coll) == 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection') {
   your code...
}
```

or

```
if ($coll instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection) {
   your code...
}
```